# Javascript, porque somente document tem o metodo getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, dom

A pegunta é simples, porque o javascript só permite fazer chamadas ao método getElementById() na raiz da árvore DOM? Em outras palavras? porque somente o objetvo document tem o método getElementById().

A razão da minha pergunta é a impossibilidade de pesquisar por um elemento de id unico a partir de um elemento qualquer.

A situação fica ainda mais curiosa quando se descobre o método querySelector() que pode ser chamado em qualquer elemento da arvore DOM, mas com uma limitação enorme: ELA NÃO PERMITE ALTERAÇÃO DOS ELEMENTOS.

então gostaria que pudessem me indicar bons materiais pra entender esse fenômeno tão contraditório.

Comment: Não teria sentido buscar por um elemento com id xyz utilizando, por exemplo,  p.getElementById('xyz'); Se tivesse 10 elementos p? Qual desses elementos p seria a referência? A interface document seria a página carregada, uma árvore e o elemento com id xyz está em alguma parte dessa árvore. Em linguagem humana eu ilustraria que getElementById('xyz') quer dizer: - Encontre xyz na árvore. Você fazer essa busca por id através de algum elemento que não seja na interface document seria algo similar fazer um select em uma "tabela A" por uma coluna "xyz" que esteja numa "tabela B" de um banco de dados

Answer (score 2):

*"querySelector() que pode ser chamado em qualquer elemento da arvore DOM,  mas com uma limitação enorme: ELA NÃO PERMITE ALTERAÇÃO DOS ELEMENTOS."*

Baseado em que está afirmando isso?
`querySelector` aplica um seletor e retorna a referência um elemeto, assim como `getElementById`, nenhum deles altera nada, quem altera são os comandos a seguir, que podem mudar as propriedades do elemento, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "ALGUMA COISA";

document.querySelector('#div2').style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
document.querySelector('#div2').innerHTML = "OUTRA COISA";


// aqui um select "a partir" de outro elemento, o primeiro input após o "div2"
document.querySelector('#div2 ~ input').value = "algum texto";
```

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border: solid 2px #000
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<input type="text" />
<div id="div2"></div>
<p>Paragrafo</p>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

*"porque o javascript só permite fazer chamadas ao método getElementById() na raiz da árvore DOM?"*
Porque o DOM quem representa toda página e os elementos nela contidos, então as consultas são feitas a partir dele, sugiro ler mais sobre DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/Document

*"porque somente o objetvo document tem o método getElementById()"*
E onde mais ele poderia estar, se é o DOM o responsável por organizar todo o documento Web? Toda a organização dos elementos na estrutura da página é feita a partir dele, pegando do link acima, temos essa definição que explica bem isso:

> A interface Document representa qualquer página da Web carregada no
> navegador e **serve como um ponto de entrada para um conteúdo da página
> da Web**, que é árvore DOM. A árvore DOM inclui elementos, tais como
>
> e , entre muitos outros. Este fornece funcionalidade
> globalmente para o documento, tal como obter o URL da página e criar
> novos elementos no documento.

Ou seja, o "Document" representa o ponto de partida.

*"a impossibilidade de pesquisar por um elemento de id unico a partir de um elemento qualquer"*

Isso eu não entendi bem, como está comparando o `getElementById` com `querySelector`, suponho que esteja procurando um elemento por ID, se o ID é único não entendo a ideia de procurar um elemento a partir de outro local que não o `Document`, que é a raiz da árvore de elementos do DOM.

Se for uma pesquisa que não é a partir do ID ai isso faz sentido, mas para isso pode-se usar os seletores do `querySelector`, como no exemplo do código acima que, a partir do div com id "div2", selecionou o primeiro input.

*"então gostaria que pudessem me indicar bons materiais pra entender esse fenômeno tão contraditório."*
Não é o objetivo do Stackoverflow PT fornecer materiais, aqui postamos respostas a perguntas com problemas específicos e quanto mais objetivos melhor, espero que a resposta ajude, mas como referência coloquei o link com a documentação do `Document` que deve ajudar a esclarecer mais dúvidas.